# How can I change the backend handler in OpenWrt system?

Tags: openwrt

Lately i am doing a project about OpenWrt.I don't know much about this Linux distrbution and it's web backend handle logic.The question is i can locate the `login` handler,I really need some help plz.

Here are some information about my OpenWrt.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uname -a
Linux OpenWrt 4.4.60 #0 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 12 03:47:00 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg list
ath11k-firmware-ipq60xx - 19
ath11k-wifi-gl-ax1800 - 1
base-files - 1450-r16399+159-c67509efd7
busybox - 1.33.2-2
ca-bundle - 20210119-1
cgi-io - 2021-09-08-98cef9dd-20
dnsmasq - 2.85-11
dropbear - 2020.81-2
firewall - 2021-03-23-61db17ed-1
fstools - 2021-07-28-cc63933f-1
fwtool - 2019-11-12-8f7fe925-1
getrandom - 2020-10-25-9ef88681-2
hostapd-common - 2021-02-20-59e9794c-3
ip6tables - 1.8.7-1
iptables - 1.8.7-1
iw - 5.9-1
iwinfo - 2021-06-09-c0414642-2.1
jshn - 2022-05-15-d2223ef9-2
jsonfilter - 2018-02-04-c7e938d6-1
kernel - 4.4.60-1-5a275068e02c23caff9109dc0a624b90
kmod-ath - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-ath11k - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-ath11k-ahb - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-ath11k-pci - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-bonding - 4.4.60-1
kmod-cfg80211 - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-gpio-button-hotplug - 4.4.60-3
kmod-ip6tables - 4.4.60-1
kmod-ipt-conntrack - 4.4.60-1
kmod-ipt-core - 4.4.60-1
kmod-ipt-nat - 4.4.60-1
kmod-ipt-offload - 4.4.60-1
kmod-lib-crc-ccitt - 4.4.60-1
kmod-mac80211 - 4.4.60+20210222_001-4.4.60-b157d2276-1
kmod-nf-conntrack - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-conntrack6 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-flow - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-ipt - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-ipt6 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-nat - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-reject - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nf-reject6 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-nls-base - 4.4.60-1
kmod-ppp - 4.4.60-1
kmod-pppoe - 4.4.60-1
kmod-pppox - 4.4.60-1
kmod-qca-nss-dp - 4.4.60-1
kmod-qca-nss-drv - 4.4.60-2
kmod-qca-nss-drv-bridge-mgr - 4.4.60+153998d70fdba508a59a28c13a606032cbf32686-2
kmod-qca-nss-drv-vlan-mgr - 4.4.60+153998d70fdba508a59a28c13a606032cbf32686-2
kmod-qca-nss-drv-wifi-meshmgr - 4.4.60+153998d70fdba508a59a28c13a606032cbf32686-2
kmod-qca-ssdk - 4.4.60-1
kmod-qrtr_mproc - 4.4.60-1
kmod-slhc - 4.4.60-1
kmod-udptunnel4 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-udptunnel6 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-usb-core - 4.4.60-1
kmod-usb-dwc3 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-usb-dwc3-qcom - 4.4.60-1
kmod-usb-phy-ipq807x - 4.4.60-1
kmod-usb3 - 4.4.60-1
kmod-wireguard-backport - 4.4.60+1.0.20211208-1
libblobmsg-json20220515 - 2022-05-15-d2223ef9-2
libc - 1.1.24-3
libgcc1 - 5.5.0-3
libip4tc2 - 1.8.7-1
libip6tc2 - 1.8.7-1
libiwinfo-data - 2021-06-09-c0414642-2.1
libiwinfo-lua - 2021-06-09-c0414642-2.1
libiwinfo20210430 - 2021-06-09-c0414642-2.1
libjson-c5 - 0.15-2
libjson-script20220515 - 2022-05-15-d2223ef9-2
liblua5.1.5 - 5.1.5-9
liblucihttp-lua - 2021-06-11-3dc89af4-1
liblucihttp0 - 2021-06-11-3dc89af4-1
libnl-tiny2022-05-17 - 2022-05-17-b5b2ba09-1
libopenssl1.1 - 1.1.1l-1
libpcre - 8.44-3
libpthread - 1.1.24-3
librt - 1.1.24-3
libubox20220515 - 2022-05-15-d2223ef9-2
libubus-lua - 2021-08-09-a72457b6-2
libubus20210809 - 2021-08-09-a72457b6-2
libuci20130104 - 2020-10-06-52bbc99f-5
libuclient20201210 - 2021-05-14-6a6011df-1
libustream-wolfssl20201210 - 2020-12-10-68d09243-1
libwolfssl4.8.1.66253b90 - 4.8.1-stable-4
libxtables12 - 1.8.7-1
logd - 2020-10-25-9ef88681-2
lua - 5.1.5-9
luci - git-20.074.84698-ead5e81
luci-app-firewall - git-21.243.76516-19c66ef
luci-app-opkg - git-21.079.58548-3bcbcbf
luci-base - git-21.284.67084-e4d24f0
luci-i18n-base-zh-cn - git-21.282.73955-9987b39
luci-i18n-firewall-zh-cn - git-21.281.68623-28b9663
luci-i18n-opkg-zh-cn - git-21.281.68623-28b9663
luci-lib-base - git-20.232.39649-1f6dc29
luci-lib-ip - git-20.250.76529-62505bd
luci-lib-json - git-18.184.37844-cde13dc
luci-lib-jsonc - git-19.317.29469-8da8f38
luci-lib-nixio - git-20.234.06894-c4a4e43
luci-mod-admin-full - git-19.253.48496-3f93650
luci-mod-network - git-21.285.33716-9aaebdf
luci-mod-rpc - git-21.020.56896-af422b1
luci-mod-status - git-21.265.39600-b5464a3
luci-mod-system - git-21.271.74796-7c943a1
luci-proto-ipv6 - git-21.148.48881-79947af
luci-proto-ppp - git-21.158.38888-88b9d84
luci-theme-bootstrap - git-21.283.63931-588e24f
mtd - 26
netifd - 2022-05-19-507c0513-1
odhcp6c - 2021-01-09-53f07e90-16
odhcpd-ipv6only - 2021-07-18-bc9d317f-3
openwrt-keyring - 2021-02-20-49283916-2
opkg - 2021-06-13-1bf042dd-1
ppp - 2.4.8.git-2020-10-03-3
ppp-mod-pppoe - 2.4.8.git-2020-10-03-3
procd - 2021-11-04-0ee8e734-4
qca-nss-fw-ipq60xx - 383
qca-ssdk-shell - 1
qca-thermald-10.4 - 1
rpcd - 2021-11-04-d11ffe93-1
rpcd-mod-file - 2021-11-04-d11ffe93-1
rpcd-mod-iwinfo - 2021-11-04-d11ffe93-1
rpcd-mod-luci - 20210614
rpcd-mod-rrdns - 20170710
swconfig - 12
ubi-utils - 2.1.2-1
uboot-envtools - 2021.01-20
ubox - 2020-10-25-9ef88681-2
ubus - 2021-08-09-a72457b6-2
ubusd - 2021-08-09-a72457b6-2
uci - 2020-10-06-52bbc99f-5
uclient-fetch - 2021-05-14-6a6011df-1
uhttpd - 2021-03-21-15346de8-2
uhttpd-mod-ubus - 2021-03-21-15346de8-2
urandom-seed - 3
urngd - 2020-01-21-c7f7b6b6-1
usign - 2020-05-23-f1f65026-1
wget-ssl - 1.21.1-1
wireless-regdb - 2021.08.28-1
wpad-openssl - 2021-02-20-59e9794c-3
zlib - 1.2.11-3


What i want to do is embed a vulnerability to `luci` . Something like when the login password is longer than 10 charactr,it allows me enter the admin page even the `password` is wrong.But i can find where the `.lua` file is about the login handler.
```

Comment: maybe it can help if you mention what your ultimate goal is...

Comment: Sorry that i write it in the other bock and it doesn't show up.What i want to do is to implant a vulnerability in the login handler, something like if I enter a password string longger than 10 characters, it allows me to enter the admin page even the password is wrong.